# How to invert volume of matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Please assume a vector of invertible matrices:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.arange(120).reshape((2, 2, 5, 6))
```

I want to invert the matrices over their defined axes:

```
b = np.linalg.inv(a, axis1=0, axis2=1)
```

but this does not seems supported.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inv` docs specifies its array input as:

```
a : (..., M, M) array_like
    Matrix to be inverted.
```

You have a

```
a = np.arange(120).reshape((2, 2, 5, 6))
(M,M,...)
```

The dimensions are in the wrong order - change them!

```
In [44]: a = np.arange(120).reshape((2, 2, 5, 6))
```

Change the axes to the order that `inv` accepts:

```
In [45]: A = a.transpose(2,3,0,1)
In [46]: Ai = np.linalg.inv(A)
In [47]: Ai.shape
Out[47]: (5, 6, 2, 2)
In [48]: ai = Ai.transpose(2,3,0,1)    # and back
In [49]: ai.shape
Out[49]: (2, 2, 5, 6)
```

I was going to test the result, but got:

```
In [50]: x = a@ai
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-50-9dfe3616745d>", line 1, in <module>
    x = a@ai
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 5 is different from 6)
```

Like `inv`, `matmul` treats the last 2 dimensions as the `matrix`, the first 2 as 'batch':

```
In [51]: x = A@Ai
In [52]: x[0,0]
Out[52]: 
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
In [53]: x[0,3]
Out[53]: 
array([[1.00000000e+00, 1.38777878e-17],
       [4.44089210e-16, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

We can do the equivalent with `einsum`:

```
In [55]: x = np.einsum('ijkl,jmkl->imkl',a,ai)
In [56]: x[:,:,0,0]
Out[56]: 
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

You might want to change the original specification to match the `inv` and `matmul` usage.  It could make life easier for you.  Also remember that in `numpy` the trailing dimensions are the inner most ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the matrices are 2x2 you can do that easily using the standard formula for inverting such matrices; otherwise, I fear the only reasonable solution would be to do it with for loops? For example, the following works for any shape (modifying the sizes adequately):

```
b = np.stack([np.linalg.inv(a[:, :, i, j]) for i in range(a.shape[2]) for j in range(a.shape[3])], axis=2)
b = b.reshape(2, 2, 5, 6)
```

as checked by

```
for i in range(a.shape[2]):
    for j in range(a.shape[3]):
        assert np.allclose(np.dot(a[:,:,i,j], b[:,:,i,j]), np.eye(2))
```

In the specific 2x2 case you can do the following, which is fully vectorized hence probably faster:

```
determinants = a[0, 0] * a[1, 1] - a[0, 1] * a[1, 0]
b = 1 / determinants * np.stack([
    np.stack([a[1, 1], -a[0, 1]]),
    np.stack([-a[1, 0], a[0, 0]]),
])
```

On the specific (small) input size, the second solution is about 10 times faster in my tests (43us vs. 537us).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582678/913098) which means yours is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? Surely that one is more elegant (and indeed I've upvoted it, I should have read the docs...), but also both solutions I've proposed work perfectly fine...

Comment: "the only reasonable solution would be to do it with for loops". "Only" is a strong word. Also, elegance is one thing, but try timing them against each other.

Comment: Well, I did put a question mark to mention that I wasn't sure :-) anyway, I did time it, on the same input the elegant solution above takes 99us, so indeed 5 times faster than the for loop but more than twice as slow as the "math" solution.